# Python: ulimit and nice for subprocess.call / subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, resources, nice, ulimit

I need to limit the amount of time and cpu taken by external command line apps I spawn from a python process using subprocess.call , mainly because sometimes the spawned process gets stuck and pins the cpu at 99%.

nice and ulimit seem like reasonable ways to do this, but I'm not sure how they'd interact with subprocess.

- The limits look something like:

  - Kill the process if it's taking more than 60 seconds
  - Limit it to 20% of cpu
- I want to apply the resource limiting to the subprocess, not to the python process that's spawning the subprocesses.

Is there a way to apply nice and ulimit to the subprocess.call spawned process? Are there better python-native alternatives?

This is on a linux (ubuntu) system.

Comment: You might want to accept the highest-voted answer instead of my answer.  It's much better than mine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set limits for subprocesses with the `ulimit` and `nice` shell commands like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('ulimit -t 60; nice -n 15 cpuhog', shell=True)
```

This runs `cpuhog` with a limit of 60 seconds of CPU time and a niceness adjustment of 15.  Note that there is no simple way to set a 20% CPU throttle as such.  The process will use 100% CPU unless another (less nice) process also needs the CPU.

Comment: Thanks Ville, the cpu throttling you describe works great. Do you know if it's possible to do the same thing specifying the command with the bracket syntax instead of as a string?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you have to pass the entire shell command in one string for something like this to work.

Comment: This is really not the solution that should be marked as accepted answer. In combination with user-supplied parameters, this can easily end up opening a security hole.

Answer (score 121):

Use the preexec_fn parameter to subprocess.Popen, and the resource module. Example:

*parent.py:*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import resource
import subprocess

def setlimits():
    # Set maximum CPU time to 1 second in child process, after fork() but before exec()
    print "Setting resource limit in child (pid %d)" % os.getpid()
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU, (1, 1))

print "CPU limit of parent (pid %d)" % os.getpid(), resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU)
p = subprocess.Popen(["./child.py"], preexec_fn=setlimits)
print "CPU limit of parent (pid %d) after startup of child" % os.getpid(), resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU)
p.wait()
print "CPU limit of parent (pid %d) after child finished executing" % os.getpid(), resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU)
```

*child.py:*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import resource

print "CPU limit of child (pid %d)" % os.getpid(), resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU)
```

*parent.py* will fork into a new process. In the new process, it will call setlimits(), then exec *child.py*. This means the resource will be limited in the child process, but not in the parent.

Output when running program:

```
./parent.py
CPU limit of parent (pid 17404) (-1, -1)
Setting resource limit in child (pid 17405)
CPU limit of parent (pid 17404) after startup of child (-1, -1)
CPU limit of child (pid 17405) (1, 1)
CPU limit of parent (pid 17404) after child finished executing (-1, -1)
```

This is in many cases a better solution than trying to use ulimit, since it's not always a good idea to spawn subprocess via shell, especially since it often causes ugly parameter quoting trouble.

Comment: Thanks Erik. It looks like this sets the limits on the python process, not on the external process?

Comment: The Python process and all of its children. (That is, the way it's supposed to be. ;) ) From the man page: Limits on the consumption of system resources by the current process and each process it creates may be obtained with the getrlimit() call, and set with the setrlimit() call.

Comment: Yes, the resource package sets the limit on the python process (via setrlimit) - but in my example, it sets the limit on the subprocess created by subproces.Popen, before calling exec() to run the child.

So, in the example, the calling process' limits is not affected, only the limits of the child.

Comment: do you guys know where I can download this `resource` package ? (for a machine not connected to the Internet)

Comment: The resource package is included in Python, but it's only available on Unix platforms. See http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it makes sense, but in this case I only need to limit the child process - the parent process actually needs to remain unlimited.

Comment: This answer is 100% correct, and should have been chosen as the correct answer.

Comment: good answer on resource limits but it doesn't address the use of `nice`

Comment: `os.nice` should be added to the answer.

Comment: To also set the nice value of the child, just add the line `os.nice(N)` (with the apropriate `N`) to the `setlimits()` function.

Comment: @Parand You and @Andrew miscommunicated. It does change only the children process limits/niceness. `Popen` forks current process, so before it calls `exec` you have two Python processes. The code in the answer will set rlimits and niceness for the children _and all of the children it creates_ - the parent will be left with its own values. This answer is correct.

Comment: Another thing that should be noted, is that using `preexec_fn` makes `Popen` thread-
***un***safe. Do not try to do anything clever inside the function you are passing to it, otherwise you might deadlock the interpreter.

Comment: See "Is `preexec_fn` ever safe in multi-threaded programs? Under what circumstances?": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72686010/is-preexec-fn-ever-safe-in-multi-threaded-programs-under-what-circumstances

Answer (score 11):

**Erik** made it easy for me, but he forgot the `nice` part which **Rich** Pointed out. I find the `psutil` package nice(pun intended) but unfortunately less portable. Here is my take at the question:

```
import os
import psutil
import resource
import subprocess

def preexec_fn():
    pid = os.getpid()
    ps = psutil.Process(pid)
    ps.set_nice(10)
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU, (1, 1))

print "mother pid", os.getpid()
p = subprocess.Popen(["./cpuhog.sh"], preexec_fn=preexec_fn)
p.wait()
print "mother still alive with pid", os.getpid()
```

**Ville** used the `shell=True` to which I'm somehow allergic. Perhaps I'm just old and grumpy here, but I try to avoid it!

Comment: Why would you need `psutil` when Python's builtin `os` already has `nice`?

Comment: Probably because you can't pass a PID to `os.nice`, but you can to `psutil`.

Comment: @cliff.wells you do not need to pass the PID of the child, `os.nice` changes niceness of current process, which at the point it runs _is_ the child.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik good point.

Comment: There's a catch to `preexec_fn`. From the official docs: "Changed in version 3.8: The preexec_fn parameter is no longer supported in subinterpreters. The use of the parameter in a subinterpreter raises RuntimeError. The new restriction may affect applications that are deployed in mod_wsgi, uWSGI, and other embedded environments."