# Resource limits (setrlimit) on mac OS X

Tags: macos, resources

I'm trying to understand how to put resource limits on a process from within that process in Mac OS X (I have 10.6). On CentOS, the following test program (python3.3) works as I expected it would:

```
import resource
import signal

def confirm(prompt, instructions='(y)es or (n)o only, please.'):
    while True:
        ok = input(prompt)
        if ok in ('y', 'ye', 'yes'):
            return True
        if ok in ('n', 'no'):
            return False
        print(instructions)

def handle_cpu_soft_limit(signal, frame):
    print('CPU soft limit reached.')
    if not confirm('Do you want to continue anyway? (y/n): '):
        raise ResourceWarning()

def long_function():
        a = 0
        while True:
            a += 1
            a -= 1

def main():
    # set soft limit to 1 second, hard limit to 5 seconds (CPU time)
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU, (1, 5))
    # set handler for soft CPU limit signal
    signal.signal(signal.SIGXCPU, handle_cpu_soft_limit)
    # do some busy work
    try:
        long_function()
    except ResourceWarning:
        print('Stopping now before being forced.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The program burns CPU time until the soft limit (1 second, the first element in the tuple passed to `resource.setrlimit()`) is reached. The program catches the signal sent by the OS (in this case, SIGXCPU) and asks me if I want to continue. On CentOS (or other linuxes), If I say yes, it will ask me again in one second intervals until the hard limit (5 seconds) is reached, at which point the OS kills the process. On Mac OS X, I still get and handle the SIGXCPU signal, but I never get the signal again, and the process is never killed, even when the hard limit is reached. This may or may not be related to what the asker of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916483/python-child-process-limits) was experiencing.

The man page for `setrlimit` on Mac OS X says the following:

> A resource limit is specified as a soft limit and a hard limit.  When a soft limit is exceeded a process may receive a signal (for example, if the cpu time or file size is exceeded), but it will be allowed to continue execution until it reaches the hard limit (or modifies its resource limit).

…which is actually from the BSD 4.2 man page on setrlimit. Nevertheless, it appears that the program never gets a SIGKILL when the hard limit is reached. I searched google and SO for information on mac setrlimit, but didn't find much that was useful. I have two questions:

1. Is this behavior (specifically mac os X ignoring hard limits on a process) intended and documented anywhere as such? I wrote my example here in python, but the same thing happens in C (I can post some test code for that here on request), so this is not a language bug.
2. Is there any way to get this code to behave the same way on linux and mac? Or should I just treat the soft limit like a hard limit on mac?