# Writing a python script that dosen't hog resources

Tags: python

I have a script which does a lot of computational work and is very resource intensive. When I am running the script (which typically takes several hours to complete), I am almost unable to use my machine, because it grinds to a halt.

I remember in the old days of VB programming, there was a `yield()` statement, which forced a memory hogging routine to be nice and hand over some CPU cycles to other processes.

My question is, is there a similar construct in Python which allows me to write scripts that play nicely with other processes on my machine?

Typical script below ....

```
# import required libs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
    do_some_expensive_calcs()  # need to periodically 'yield' to other processes here - how do I do it?
```

Comment: You can be `nice`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689505/python-ulimit-and-nice-for-subprocess-call-subprocess-popen

Comment: The problem with memory hogging processes is that they force everything into swap. If this is what is happening to you then freeing the CPU isn't going to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also do this from within the script itself with the OS package:

```
import os
os.nice(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a *ix machine, start your program nicely:

```
nice ./prog
```

You can also "renice" the program while it is running, e.g. with `top`.

The other strategy which I always worth thinking about is to improve the algorithm.